# How to trigger the Access Ribbon's Create 'Table Design' button via vba?

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

**Background**

Developing an application used by internal data managers (familiar w/ database schema & table design). One portion of the application includes a CSV import functionality with mapping between the CSV's "columns" and those of existing tables.

Users will also want to create new tables to import into. To make this as user friendly as possible, I'd like to include a button which opens a new (but not yet created) table in design view like the "Table Design" button found in the Access database ribbon (see below).

[image]

While I know the user can go to the ribbon and click the button, having it trigger from a button on the form makes it clearer for the user working with the CSV imports/import mapping.

**Problem**

Is there a direct command for triggering the "Table Design" button (or its action/function) via vba?

Perhaps something on the order of

`DoCmd.OpenForm "Table Design", acNormal`

Or something that will trigger the action of the typical MS Access button visible on the "Create" tab?

Comment: Record clicking it and see. `Alt + T, M, R` repeat to stop recording. Press Alt + F11 and look at the macro Excel wrote. While there press F2 to view all methods/properties/functions/constants/etc.

Comment: @ACatInLove Unfortunately, AFAIK MS Access doesn't have a VBA code recorder.  (Have to be careful - can't call it a "macro recorder" because Access has macros as well as VBA, so Access developers think of something else when they hear "macro".)

Comment: There still object browser.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you want is `DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdNewObjectDesignTable`.

Here is some documentation: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/access-vba/articles/application-runcommand-method-access

Comment: Excellent this was *exactly* what I was looking for! Thank you.